# Why am I unable to generate client side code in web services 'Hello world' example?

Tags: java, web-services

Link is: http://people.apache.org/~ruchithf/hw-axis2/.

Command line is: `javac -extdirs d:\lib\ D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\*.java -d d:\clientcode\`

The Error is:

```
C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>javac -extdirs
d:\lib\ D:\stub\src\org\apache
\ws\axis2\*.java -d d:\clientcode\
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:3:
cannot find symbol symbol  : class
EchoRequest location: class
org.apache.ws.axis2.SimpleServiceStub
import
org.apache.ws.axis2.SimpleServiceStub.EchoRequest;
                                            ^
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:12:
cannot find symbol symbol  : class
EchoRequest location: class
org.apache.ws.axis2.Client EchoRequest
request = new
SimpleServiceStub.EchoRequest(); ^
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:12:
cannot find symbol symbol  : class
EchoRequest location: class
org.apache.ws.axis2.SimpleServiceStub
EchoRequest request = new
SimpleServiceStub.EchoRequest();
                                           ^ Note:
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\SimpleServiceStub.java
uses unchecked or u nsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked
for details. 3 errors C:\Program
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin>javac -extdirs
d:\lib\ D:\stub\src\org\apache
\ws\axis2\*.java -d d:\clientcode\
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:3:
cannot find symbol symbol  : class
EchoRequest location: class
org.apache.ws.axis2.SimpleServiceStub
import
org.apache.ws.axis2.SimpleServiceStub.EchoRequest;
                                            ^
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:12:
cannot find symbol symbol  : class
EchoRequest location: class
org.apache.ws.axis2.Client EchoRequest
request = new
SimpleServiceStub.EchoRequest(); ^
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\Client.java:12:
cannot find symbol symbol  : class
EchoRequest location: class
org.apache.ws.axis2.SimpleServiceStub
EchoRequest request = new
SimpleServiceStub.EchoRequest();
                                           ^ Note:
D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\axis2\SimpleServiceStub.java
uses unchecked or u nsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked
for details. 3 errors
```

Comment: could you please block-quote the error so the formatting isn't lost?

Comment: Done, not sure how much this is going to help though.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Axis library really is in D:\stub\src\org\apache\ws\

...and try using double-backslashes: D:\\stub\\src\\org\\apache\\ws and d:\\lib

I can't re-create your problem since I'm using Linux, and I remember Windows users having backslash issues sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the axis stub generator is old, and generates pre 1.5 (maybe even pre 1.4) java source code. Try setting the source flag, and see what happens.